# Game Maker: create an ennemy at a random position on the ground

Tags: game-maker, gml

I know a bit about coding (in Python, C and XHTML) and I'm trying to understand the basics of Game Maker. I have created a room with enemies moving, colliding to the walls and all, but now, I'd like to randomly spawn enemies in the room **as long as they are on a ground**. For now, it only works when I spawn them randomly.

Here is the code I put in the Create event of the `obj_enemy` but obviously something isn't working since it does not spawn any enemy at all.

Also, don't know if it matters, but if I haven't already placed myself an `obj_enemy` in the room, they do not spawn neither...

```
// INIT //
dir = -1;      // direction
movespeed = 3; // movement speed
hsp = 0;       // horizontal speed
vsp = 0;       // vertical speed
grav = 0.5;    // gravity

// CREATE //
// Find a random X position in the room
var randx = random(room_width);
// Find a random Y position in the room
var randy = random(room_height);

// If the random position is empty
if position_empty (randx, randy)
{
    // If there is a block
    // 16 pixels under
    // the random Y position
    // (the sprite of obj_enemy is 32x32 pixels)
    if place_meeting (randx, randy+16, obj_block01)
    {
        // If there is less than 4 ennemies
        if instance_number (obj_ennemy) <= 4
        {
            // Create an ennemy
            instance_create(randx, randy, obj_ennemy);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: My room]

Comment: In your code it says 'obj_ennemy' with 2 n's by the way. That might be your problem.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry, that's because in french you say 'ennemi' with two n's and I just noticed it's not the same spelling in english, so I changed it when correcting this post, but forgot to change it in the code. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

This is the create event of obj_enemy. if there are no obj_enemy's in the room then this code will never get run!

You either need to start with at least one enemy in the room or create a controller object in charge of creating enemies that you put into the room instead (I recommend this approach).

Also even if the code does get run then the chances of spawning an enemy just over a wall in the correct location is quite small so you will have to run the program many times before you see it happen. To avoid this just put the spawn code into a while true loop and break from it once 4 enemies have been spawned:

```
while (instance_number (obj_ennemy) <= 4)
{
// Find a random X position in the room
var randx = random(room_width);
// Find a random Y position in the room
var randy = random(room_height);

// If the random position is empty
if position_empty (randx, randy)
{
    // If there is a block
    // 16 pixels under
    // the random Y position
    // (the sprite of obj_enemy is 32x32 pixels)
    if place_meeting (randx, randy+16, obj_block01)
    {

       // Create an ennemy
       instance_create(randx, randy, obj_ennemy);
     }

}
}
```